# Where does each item level and affix drop?

Tags: diablo-iii

I understand that item level determines where an item can drop (act/difficulty) and what affixes it can have, but I am having trouble finding information that clearly states the following:

1. The earliest act/difficulty where you can find each item level, and
2. The item levels for each range of each affix.

For the former, I have only found information about ilvl 60 - 63 but I would like information for all item levels.  For the latter I have only found [this page](http://www.diablofans.com/topic/41045-spoiler-diablo-iii-item-affixes/) linked on another question, but it's not clear where each "tier" of affix can drop.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question (item/monster levels), I came across a chart someone made to illustrate experience gain, but which can be applied to this as well.

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbadP.jpg)

[Source thread on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Diablo/comments/uabo2/d3_exp_chart_updated_may_29_2012/) by "Malloy626"

Basically, the cells marked as 100% will be the min, mid and max monster levels in each Act. I doubt all the data is entirely correct, but it gives a good indication on what maximum item levels to expect.

Comment: Thank you, that's a start.  :-)  To be sure, can monsters only drop things with items levels equal or less than their character (er, monster?) level?  For example, if a monster is level 18, does that mean it can only drop ilvl 18 and lower?  Or is it messier than that?

Comment: @Nattie Can't say for sure. At least on Inferno _so far_ the monsters will only drop items their level or below. This will change in the next patch, however, so it's not a definite gameplay mechanic. I do imagine that it's somewhat related though, and I don't think monsters generally can drop items higher than their own level.

Answer (score 0):

I managed this find [this](http://d3inferno.com/affixes/ItemAffixes.html), which is laid out sorta weird, but if you click on any particular affix it will tell you the "affix level," and I think it corresponds to item level; e.g. something that is affix level 43 is only on ilvl 43 and above.  I don't have confirmation of that, though.